# Anyway to alert me when a Mount Point stops

Tags: icecast

I am trying to get notified as soon as a icecast Mount Point gets disconnected. The issue we are having is that my station, seems to sometimes drop the live stream from the studio (normally when on air talent stuff up.)

While I can't stop these stuff ups, surely there is away I can make a script that runs on the studio computer to turn the studio mic on, if the presenter has not played music nor turned mic on when they are meant to.

I understand that this may create other issues but one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on-disconnect` parameter of `Mount Specific Settings` will run a script when a mount point disconnects, I've been using this for something similar for a few years, works a charm